# The wrong language is shown in App Store!

Tags: iphone, localization, app-store

Last week I distributed my first app to the App Store. what i've to see was, that the app language which is shown in appstore is not the right one. my app is just in German, but in App Store english is shown up.

Can somebody tell me what I've exactly got to do, so that the language in the appstore is German? I know I need a "de.lproj" folder, but i don't know what this folder should contain and what I've got to do step by step to realize that the right way.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is write "German" (without the quotes) at the "Localization native development region" property in your info.plist file of you application.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to mention the default language of your application in your info.plist file.