# Norwegian localisation in iOS application

Tags: iphone, localization

I have an iPhone app which is supposed to be in Norwegian. All my nib files and content are in Norwegian. Then I came to know about language files (Localisation), but I can't see Norwegian in the list of languages in the App Store. Why is this? How can I enable Norwegian localisation for the app using these language files?

Answer (score 1):

If you want your app to be listed in the App Store as Norwegian, you may want to try to add a folder called `no.lproj` to your project (with some data inside), and then submit/update your application.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418652/set-ios-application-language-in-itunes/5712735#5712735) answer on another thread. It has been accepted as correct by the guy asking the question, so I'm just assuming that it worked. Please let me know if it worked or not, as I have to try this later on myself when I have the time.

I hope that helps, good luck.

EDIT: You can also try to edit your info.plist file. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757757/the-wrong-language-is-shown-in-app-store) thread.

Answer (score 0):

There are other [Norwegian apps](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/iradio-norsk/id331038509?mt=8) on the app store, and they come up in the app store as "Norwegian." Where are you running into trouble?