# Setting iOS application languages in iTunes

Tags: ios4, app-store, universal-binary, itunes-store

I want to set the application language in iTunes. It always shows only English, but I want to show two languages in iTunes. I don’t want to make any changes to the application code, as I’m already managing these two languages by device language.

[image: Sample Image]

The sample image contains multiple languages, like English, Chinese, Dutch, and French.

Comment: Hi @MiteshKhatri and welcome to StackOverflow! There's a proposal in the works for questions specifically about App Stores. Please [have a look](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30702/app-store). Feel free to follow it if you have an interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same issue currently, and even if I fill different languages in iTunes Connect, I still have only English.
I'll try something else, just by adding en.lproj & xx.lproj (replace xx by country language two caracters code) in my app with some data inside. I think when you submit an app, this is where Apple collect the list of available languages). I hope this will works!

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the localizations via iTunes Connect. Choose you application from the list and click Manage Localizations. However, if your app is currently in review or approved, you need to submit a new binary:

> You cannot add a new language from
>   this page because your app has either
>   already been approved or is currently
>   in review. To add a new language, you
>   must submit a new version of your app.

Comment: Thanks for reply. i already added localization for german language. but all other text are showing German but it always show      language =English. i want to change it to German.

Comment: You may have to contact iTunes Connect support to sort that out.

Comment: iTunes Connect doesn't allow changes for application versions that are already for sale. That looks like your only option.